# Throwing exception on NIO SSL Handshake process using SSLEngine

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, nio, jsse

I am getting following exception on NIO SSL handshake. During handshake process,

On client side,

a) NEED_WRAP

b) NEED_UNWRAP

c) NEED_TASK

d) NEED_UNWRAP - getting the following exception on calling unwrap.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Handshake message sequence violation, 1
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Handshaker.java:1371)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(SSLEngineImpl.java:513)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:790)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:758)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
    at com.ipay.ssl.SSlClientNio.doHandshake(SSlClientNio.java:65)
    at com.ipay.ssl.SSlClientNio.main(SSlClientNio.java:220)
javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Handshake message sequence violation, 1
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:133)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:808)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:806)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Handshaker.java:1299)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Please tell me if handshake sequence i am following is correct. I am completely stuck on handshaking part.

//Editied

Following is the handshake code.

```
void doHandshake(SelectionKey key, SSLEngine engine,
            ByteBuffer myNetData, ByteBuffer peerNetData) throws Exception {

        SocketChannel socketChannel = (SocketChannel)key.channel();
        // Create byte buffers to use for holding application data
        int appBufferSize = engine.getSession().getApplicationBufferSize();
        ByteBuffer myAppData = ByteBuffer.allocate(appBufferSize);

        // Begin handshake
        engine.beginHandshake();
        SSLEngineResult.HandshakeStatus hs = engine.getHandshakeStatus();
        System.out.println("handshake"+hs);

        // Process handshaking message
        while (hs != SSLEngineResult.HandshakeStatus.FINISHED &&
            hs != SSLEngineResult.HandshakeStatus.NOT_HANDSHAKING) {
             switch (hs) {
                case NEED_UNWRAP:
                System.out.println("Reached NEED UNWRAP");
                // Receive handshaking data from peer
                if (socketChannel.read(myNetData) < 0) {
                    // Handle closed channel
                    System.out.println("not able toRead data from channel to buffer at client");
                }
                myNetData.flip();
                // Process incoming handshaking data
                if(myNetData.limit() == 0)
                {
                    myNetData.clear();
                    break;
                }
                myAppData.clear();
                System.out.println("checking limit"+myNetData.limit());
                SSLEngineResult res = engine.unwrap(myNetData, myAppData);
                myNetData.compact();
                // Getting handshake status
                hs = res.getHandshakeStatus();
                System.out.println("Debugging in NEED_UNWRAP-->"+hs);
                // Check status
                switch (res.getStatus()) {
                case OK :
                    // Handle OK status
                    System.out.println("OK");
                    break;
                case BUFFER_OVERFLOW:
                    System.out.println("BUFFER OVERFLOW");
                    break;
                case BUFFER_UNDERFLOW:
                    System.out.println("BUFFER UNDERFLOW");
                    break;
                case CLOSED:
                    System.out.println("CLOSED");
                    break;

                // Handle other status: BUFFER_UNDERFLOW, BUFFER_OVERFLOW, CLOSED
               // ...
                }
                break;
            case NEED_WRAP :
                System.out.println("Reached NEED WRAP");
                // Empty the local network packet buffer.
                myNetData.clear();
                // Generate handshaking data
                res = engine.wrap(myAppData, myNetData);
                // Getting handshake status
                hs = res.getHandshakeStatus();
                System.out.println("Debugging in NEED_WRAP-->"+hs);
                System.out.println(engine.getSession().getApplicationBufferSize());
                System.out.println(myNetData.capacity());
                // Check status
                switch (res.getStatus()) {
                case OK :
                    System.out.println("OK");
                    myNetData.flip();

                    // Send the handshaking data to peer
                    while (myNetData.hasRemaining()) {
                        if (socketChannel.write(myNetData) < 0) {
                            // closing socket channel
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case BUFFER_OVERFLOW:
                    System.out.println("BUFFER OVERFLOW");
                    break;
                case BUFFER_UNDERFLOW:
                    System.out.println("BUFFER UNDERFLOW");
                    break;
                case CLOSED:
                    System.out.println("CLOSED");
                    break;
                // Handle other status:  BUFFER_OVERFLOW, BUFFER_UNDERFLOW, CLOSED
               // ...
                }
                    break;
            case NEED_TASK :
                System.out.println("NEED TASK");
                System.out.println("Debugging in NEED_TASK-->"+hs);
                Runnable task;

                while((task=engine.getDelegatedTask()) != null)
                {
                System.out.println("Inside while loop");
                ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
                executorService.execute(task);

                // Handle blocking tasks
                }
                // Whether following code is required
                hs=engine.getHandshakeStatus();
                System.out.println("Printing"+engine.getHandshakeStatus());
                break;
            case FINISHED:
                System.out.println("Debugging in FINISHED-->"+hs);
                System.out.println("handshake done");
                break;

            //...
            }
        }

        // Processes after handshaking
        //...
    }
```

//UPDATED EXCEPTION...

I am getting following exception on server side.
I googled it.But getting no idea.

Please help me on this part..

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Handshake message sequence violation, state = 1, type=1   
javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Handshake message sequence violation, state = 1, type = 1        

    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(Unknown Source)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(Unknown Source)
    at com.ipay.ssl.SSLServerNio.doHandshake(SSLServerNio.java:55)
    at com.ipay.ssl.SSLServerNio.main(SSLServerNio.java:216)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Handshake message sequence violation, state = 1, type = 1
    at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

varghese

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not supposed to 'follow' a 'sequence' when using the `SSLEngine`. You are supposed to *react* to the states and exceptions it provides:

- `NEED_WRAP`: do a `wrap()` from the application send buffer to the network send buffer
- `NEED_UNWRAP`: do an `unwrap()` from the network receive buffer to the application receive buffer
- `BUFFER_OVERFLOW`: do a `flip()/write()/compact()` on the network send buffer, or a `flip()/get()/compact()` on the application receive buffer
- `BUFFER_UNDERFLOW`: do a `read()` on the network receive buffer, or there is nothing in the application send buffer.

**EDIT** What's this?

```
if(myNetData.limit() == 0)
{
    myNetData.clear();
}
```

and this?

```
case NEED_WRAP:
    myNetData.clear();
```

You can't just throw away engine data. Get rid of these altogether. You can't do anything to the network send or receive buffers except `flip(), compact(), wrap(),` and `unwrap().` Also it doesn't appear that you have separate net send and receive buffers. You need both. You need *four* altogether: net send, net receive, application send, and application receive. The network buffers need to be of the sizes advised by the `SSLEngine.`

Apart from that, you aren't really *reacting* exactly as I said above. For example, take the `NEED_UNWRAP` path. You should:

1. `unwrap()` from the net recv buffer to the application receive buffer.
2. If you *then* get `BUFFER_UNDERFLOW`, `read()` into the net receive buffer and repeat (1).

For `NEED_WRAP`:

3. `wrap()` from the application send buffer to the network send buffer.
4. If you then get `BUFFER_OVERFLOW`, `write()` from the net send buffer and repeat 3.

When you need to read application data:

5. `flip()/get()/compact()` from the application receive buffer.
6. If that results in a `BufferUnderflowException`, `unwrap()` and repeat, bearing in mind that the `unwrap()` may cause `NEED_WRAP` or `NEED_WRAP` or `BUFFER_UNDERFLOW` or `BUFFER_OVERFLOW.`

When you need to write application data:

7. `put()` into the application send buffer.
8. If that results in a `BufferOverflowException`, `flip()/wrap()/compact()`, bearing in mind that the `wrap()` may cause `NEED_WRAP` or `NEED_WRAP` or `BUFFER_UNDERFLOW` or `BUFFER_OVERFLOW`.

Comment: Thanks.Actually i am not following the sequence. Once it start handshaking , above was the flow happening. One more doubt from _NEED_TASK_, how to continue with rest part in handshake(wrap/unwrap) ; currently i am using `engine.getHandshakestatus()` to switch to wrap/unwrap from need_task. Could you tell me what is that exception point to?

Comment: You can't do anything else until the task finishes, if that's what you're asking. You need to post some code.